# How to get text from Multiple EditTexts in a activity to other activity?

Tags: android

Hey guys I'm new to android.I had to make a dynamic table through table layout in which user can add as much rows as much he want. In table there is edittext in each column.Now I have to get this table with its data in other activity .or I would say when user press Ok button he goes to the other activity where this table and the data that he has entered will be shown to him. Now I need your help that how can I do this? I have made a cont variable and through putExtra. I have gotten its value so that I can make the same table into other activity. and I have added the edittexts into a arraylist then send them into a string so that I can pass it also to other activity. But its not working .I'm stuck completely and really need your help.

```
   button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
   button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ok);
   button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              count++;
               // tablelayout.removeAllViews();
                BuildTable();
            }
        });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
                strings[i] = allEds.get(i).getText().toString();
            }


            Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),Activity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("value", count);
            intent.putExtra("val", size);
            intent.putExtra("str",  strings);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
}

public void BuildTable(){

        int col=3;
        row = new TableRow(this);
       row.setId(row.generateViewId());
       row.setLayoutParams(new          TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        for (int j = 1; j <= col; j++) {

             et= new EditText(this);
            et.setId(et.generateViewId());


              et.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            et.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            allEds.add(et);

            row.addView(et);

        }

        tablelayout.addView(row);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store your editText values into an `ArrayList` of Strings. Then you can pass this arraylist to next activity via intent.

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("key_name", arrayList);
```

Answer (score 0):

On the SecondActivity

```
  Intent result = getIntent();
  String[] s ;
  if(result.hasExtra("str"))
    {
        s = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("str");
        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++)
           Log.i("string", s[i]);
    }
   int size = result.getIntExtra("val",0);
```